# Каждый HTTP-запрос запускается в отдельной горутине?

Tags: golang, синхронизация

Стандартный пакет `net/http`. Есть код:

```golang
http.HandleFunc("/", someFoo)
http.ListenAndServe(addr, nil)
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что `someFoo` будет вызвана в рамках новой горутины? То есть, выполнение каждого запроса в `net/http` ведется каждый раз в новой горутине, и мне следует синхронизировать доступ через каналы?

Было бы супер увидеть кусочек кода, в котором происходит запуск данной горутины.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что `someFoo` будет вызвана в рамках новой горутины?

Да.

> То есть, выполнение каждого запроса в `net/http` ведется каждый раз в новой горутине, и мне следует синхронизировать доступ через каналы?

Да. Или другие синхронизационные примитивы.

> Было бы супер увидеть кусочек кода, в котором происходит запуск данной горутины.

https://tip.golang.org/src/net/http/server.go

```golang
c := srv.newConn(rw)
c.setState(c.rwc, StateNew) // before Serve can return
go c.serve(ctx)
```